# Yii form submit using $_POST but no $_POST data

Tags: php, forms, post, yii

I have created a Yii application for a client, which all works good with no problems locally and on my server which was used during testing.  The client has moved the application to their server, which is where it will be hosted and when one variable on one form (there is only this form and a login form) is entered, then no $_POST are recorded by php.  The field is an optional field.

Does anybody have any ideas what is causing this to happen?

The form view is below

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
       'id'=>'clothing-knowledge-hub-form',
       'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
       'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'headerText'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'headerText',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'headerText'); ?><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'videoPath'); ?>
            Only enter a valid video embed path here. <br/>(This will overide the detail page image - image541x491 for this page)<br/>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'videoPath',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'videoPath'); ?><br/><br/>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'bodyText'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'bodyText',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'bodyText'); ?><br/>
</div>



<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'findOutMore'); ?>
            This will enable the 'Find Out More' button on the detail page.<br/> To enable it, please enter a valid url <?php //(include http:// or https://)?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'findOutMore',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>510)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'findOutMore'); ?>
            <br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'referencesText'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'referencesText',array('rows'=>4, 'cols'=>100)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'referencesText'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image300x226'); ?>Please ensure all images are optimised, (max file size 1mb) and are either jpg, jpeg, pngs or gif.<br/>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image300x226',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>510)); ?><br/>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'image300x226'); ?>
            <?php echo 'Existing image file name: '.$model['image300x226'];?><br/>
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/<?php echo $model['image300x226'];?>"><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image300x473');?>Please ensure all images are optimised, (max file size 1mb) and are either jpg, jpeg, pngs or gif.<br/>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image300x473',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>510)); ?><br/>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'image300x473'); ?>
            <?php echo 'Existing image file name: '.$model['image300x473'];?><br/>
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/<?php echo $model['image300x473'];?>"><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image541x491').' Detail Page Image'; ?><br/>Please ensure all images are optimised, (max file size 1mb) and are either jpg, jpeg, pngs or gif. 
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'image541x491',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>510)); ?><br/>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'image541x491'); ?>
            <?php echo 'Existing image file name: '.$model['image541x491'];?><br/>
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/images/<?php echo $model['image541x491'];?>"><br/><br/>
</div>

<div class="row">
            <br/>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'imageCredit'); ?>
            Html hyper links must include http:// or will result in a broken link<br/>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'imageCredit',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->error($model,'imageCredit'); ?><br/>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
 </div><!-- form -->
```

The controller action is below

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_POST), 'vardump');
    if(isset($_POST['ClothingKnowledgeHub']))
    {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['ClothingKnowledgeHub']);

                    $file1 = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image300x226');
                    if($file1 != null){
                        $uniqueId = uniqid();
                        //$extra = Yii::app()->fileName->fileName();
                        $model->image300x226 = $uniqueId.'-'.$file1->name;
                    }

                    $file2 = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image300x473');
                    if($file2 != null){
                        $uniqueId = uniqid();
                        $model->image300x473 = $uniqueId.'-'.$file2->name;
                    }

                    $file3 = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image541x491');
                    if($file3 != null){
                        $uniqueId = uniqid();
                        $model->image541x491 = $uniqueId.'-'.$file3->name;
                    }

                    if(strpos($model->findOutMore, 'http') === false){
                        $model->findOutMore = 'http://'.$model->findOutMore;
                    }
        if($model->save()){
                        if($file1 != null){
                            $file1->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../images/".$model->image300x226);

                        }
                        if($file2 != null){
                            $file2->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../images/".$model->image300x473);

                        }
                        if($file3 != null){   
                            $file3->saveAs(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../images/".$model->image541x491);

                        }
                        echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($_POST['ClothingKnowledgeHub']), 'var_dump');
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                    }
                    else {
                    ?><script type="text/javascript"> window.alert("There has been a problem saving your changes, please try again.")</script>
                    <?php  
                    }

    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm sure it's a matter of case sensitivity.

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Clear the controller action so it does nothing with the data, except for the initial render. Then simply do <?php print_r($_POST); ?> on the page. When submitting it should return to the same page with the POST information. Make sure your POST is visible and correct before developing the action.

Comment: Could be $_POST['ClothingKnowledgeHub'] is incorrect. This will depend on the model passed to the form.  From your code we cannot tell. Do this: Check the HTML code in the browser and look for <textarea ... name="YourClass[bodyText] ...> for example. The "YourClass should be ClothingKnowledgeHub according to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  There are no errors produced that I know of. It works fine if there is not some text in the findOutMore input.  I have checked spelling and it is OK.  If I do a var_dump($_POST); with the input empty then I have an array, if something is in there the it shows 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to cactiveform widget

```
'method'=>'Post',
```

also this may help.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm

Comment: This has no effect.  Thank you for your suggestion.